# Run garbagecollection in lua script in splash

Tags: lua, scrapy-splash

I have lua script in scrapy-splash:

```
...
collectgarbage("collect")
...
```

But in splash logs I am getting error:

```
2020-06-09 11:14:54 [scrapy_splash.middleware] WARNING: Bad request to Splash: {'error': 400, 'type': 'ScriptError', 'description': 'Error happened while executing Lua script', 'info': {'source': '[string "..."]', 'line_number': 43, 'error': "attempt to call global 'collectgarbage' (a nil value)", 'type': 'LUA_ERROR', 'message': 'Lua error: [string "..."]:43: attempt to call global \'collectgarbage\' (a nil value)'}}
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

The log message says that scrape-splash does not expose `collectgarbage` to the user.

Comment: @Grzegorzg, no I don't. You'll have to refer to the scrape-splash documentation.